# How to update other component state from a form component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have to different functional component.

1. AllCourses
2. AddCourses

Both are two different pages.

AllCourses component displays all the courses where I used an array of object.

Now from AddCourses component where I used form to add course.
How can I update or add new course to the AllCourses from AddCourses.

I am posting from my mobile
Thanks.

Comment: you need to pass the state to the parent component and pass it as props to children so you can update the state or you can use redux.

Comment: use redux or context api -> state management library for reflecting all the updated changes all over the website.

Comment: Send new course as newcourse property to AllCourses component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just a simple app for practice and dont need complex state management, then all you need to do is declare the `courses` state at your parent component that contains both of your All Courses and Add Courses page. This parent component could just be your `app.js`

Then create a function in your `app.js` that pushes a new course object to your courses array state. After that, pass that function to your Add Courses page as props and use it there to add a course from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the props for sending data from one component to another,
here I am sending data from parent component (AllCourses.js) to child component (AddCourses.js).

```
AllCourses.js

import React from 'react'
import AddCourses from './AddCourses.js';

class AllCourses extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <AddCourses course="Data from AddCourses"/>
    </div>
      );
   }
}

export default AllCourses;
```

```
AddCourses.js

import React from 'react';
const AddCourses = (props) => {
    return(
          <h1> {props.message} </h2> //You can add form here and pass the value of the form 
    );
}
export default AddCourses;
```

For sending data between Child to parent or siblings to siblings you can refer to the blog
[Use of Props to transfer Data between Components](https://dev.to/dipakkr/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-other-component-in-react-35i2)